# How to render images that have a transparent background using oCanvas.js

Tags: image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been designing an app with oCanvas.js. It's a really nice canvas library that makes it much easier to create an app that can create and manipulate images, but I ran into a snag when I was trying to implement image filters:

I need transparent backgrounds so that I can have multiple layers, each of which is represented by its own display object, rendered separately (meaning one at a time) on a hidden "staging" canvas.  Immediately after being rendered, a layer is then drawn on top of the previous layers on the visible canvas, so that different image filters can be applied to each layer independently during render.

The issue I am having is that, when attempting to extract the image from an oCanvas object's canvasElement, the resulting images never have a transparent background. For example: Imagine I have a 50x50 canvas that has been oCanvas.create() processed, but has display: none; (this is used as the rendering canvas) and another canvas (same dimensions) without an oCanvas instance. I am trying to do something like this (Pseudocode):

```
visibleCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(MyOcanvasCore.canvasElement,  0,  0);
```

I have also tried using `URL = MyOcanvasCore.canvasElement.toDataURL()` and then having my `visibleCanvas` do a  drawImage with `src=url`.

The images always transfer, but they have a white background, even though I specify background: "transparent" during canvas.create(). As such, they completely overwrite all previous layers.

Do you have any tips for me? Am I doing it wrong? I tried transferring stuff from one canvas to another using classic drawRect, drawImage, etc methods, and transparency was retained. That's why I believe it is either the library or my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess you are using the image format other than png. 
>   You should have your image format in PNG which keeps all the details of every pixel >including transparency of pixels
>   and not a compressed format.
>   So just try keep your image in png format after edting them in some image editor and save > result as .png .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the issue is occurring even with shapes that the oCanvas object renders. :-(

Comment: I have not used oCanvas, but for your shape rendering problem 
 may be you are not giving right information about locations of image  for your original one or at the time of drawing.